# Basic manipulation on Arrays at C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem that I can't solve :(
here it is:

I need to change line 15 here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a[MAX], b[MAX], c[MAX], i;

    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) //fill array a    a1=1   a2=2
        a[i] = i+1;

    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) //fill array b    b1=10  b2=9
        b[i] = a[MAX-1-i];

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++) //print array c
        printf("%d ",c[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

(

the line:

c[i] = a[i] + b[i];

)

so the program will print first MAX/2 elements from array a
and the last MAX/2 elements from array b.

I can't think of a way to do it :(
i'll be glad if someone could help me.

thanks!

Comment: Do you want your output to be `10, 10, 10, 10...`?

Comment: You are printing the elements of array `c`. Why do you say "so the program will print first MAX/2 elements from array a and the last MAX/2 elements from array b"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an `if` statement, something like:

```
for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
     if(i < MAX/2)
          c[i] = a[i];
     else 
          c[i] = b[i];
```

Alternatively you could get fancy and do the code on the same line with a ternary operator (`?:`):

```
for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    c[i] = (i < MAX/2)? a[i]: b[i];
```

Comment: BTW i rly like the fancy way, so '?' is like (if) and ':' is like (else)? ... i should use it more :)